# nth-child(1) giving background color to entire body element instead of just div

Tags: css

Here is my code

```css
:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
</div>
```

Now `div` is the first child of `body` element, so its background color will be changed to blue. But I see that entire body's background color is changed. `body` element is actually second child of root `html` element. What's happening ?

Comment: the html element is an :nth-child(1) as well, make your selector more specific

Comment: @Temani, html is child of whom ? Its the root element.

Comment: it doesn't need to a be a child of anything, it's an element part of the DOM so it can be selected and all the selectors apply to it (including nth-child, nth-of-type and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo):

> The :nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n. **It is not required to have a parent**.

The selector is more concerned by the siblings than the parent element so in your case the `html` element is also selected because it's the first element among its siblings (it's alone in that list)

Even in the new version of [the Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-nth-child-pseudo), it's always about siblings and never the parent

> The :nth-child(An+B [of S]? ) pseudo-class notation represents elements that are among An+Bth elements from the list composed of **their inclusive siblings** that match the selector list S

Comment: Thanks for giving reference. makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that you are trying to give the first paragraph element a blue background. You could use something like this below:

```css
div p:first-of-type {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```